# django-rest disalow get requests for ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I only want data to be sent using POST to this api endpoint. Is there a way to set which request methods are allowed?

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the whole `ViewSet` or will a normal `GenericView` be sufficient? You could use the [`CreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#createapiview).

Example:

```
class FooCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    Model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

EDIT:

If you do need to use a `ViewSet`, you could create a custom Router that will only handle `post` requests. Documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#custom-routers), including a read-only (i.e. `get`) example.

Comment: Thanks, the CreateAPIView was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -2):

There is probably a better solution, but what I did normally is

```
if request.method != 'POST':
       return Http404
```

but this seems to have the answer you need:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/

Comment: Just a note: decorators work slightly differently with class-based views as opposed to function-based views. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views).

Comment: yeah as you can see from my first response I have been using function-based views a lot...:)